# Extract XML info from feed?

Tags: xml, xpath, request

I try to extract specific data from an xml feed that comes from youtube.

XML link: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/WFPnl8aEPgo?alt=rss

I've been able to extract info like:

**Title,
Description**

using this query string:

> Dim Title As String =
>   videoInfoNavigator.SelectSingleNode("/item[1]/title").Value

However, I'm not able to find the proper query string to get info like

**media:keywords**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `media:keywords` use the **media** *namespace prefix*, which is bound to the *namespace-uri* `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/`

If you can register the namespace prefix, you could use an XPATH like this:

```
/item[1]/media:group/media:keywords
```

However, if you need a more generic XPATH that does not rely on the namespace prefix, you could express it like this:

```
/item[1]/*[local-name()='group' and namespace-uri()='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/']/*[local-name()='keywords' and namespace-uri()='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/']
```

Applied to your example code:

```
Dim Keywords As String = videoInfoNavigator.SelectSingleNode("/item[1]/*[local-name()='group' and namespace-uri()='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/']/*[local-name()='keywords' and namespace-uri()='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/']").Value
```

Comment: Thanks exemple is working like a charm.
I need to study more this exampe as i dont understand the XML much yet :)
THAAANKK !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("m", "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
var keywords = doc.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/item/m:group/m:keywords", ns);
Console.WriteLine(keywords.Value);
```

Note that the prefix you use doesn't matter at all. It's just an abbreviation for the namespace.